# In Firestore, should I call transaction.set multiple times on the same document, or reduce the fields into a single object?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

EDIT: I would recommend using Option A and calling transaction multiple times. It reads cleaner (imo) than in-line loops. Additionally, if you are using nested objects, then `example: Object.keys(obj).reduce(fn, {})` will overwrite the example field even with {merge: true}.

I need to record how many times each item and some of its properties are encountered in a given day

```
const item = {
    number: 3,
    arr: ['qwer', 'asdf', 'zxcv'],
    // Nested objects also occur, but would make this question too long.
}
```

Are either of the below options incorrect:

**A. Calling set on the same document multiple times**

```
transaction.set(dayRef, {
    number: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.number)
}, {merge: true})

item.arr.forEach(str => transaction.set(dayRef, {
    arr: {
        [str]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.number)
    }   ​
}, {merge: true})
```

**B. Reducing the properties into a single set call**

```
transaction.set(dayRef, {
    ​number: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.number),
    arr: item.arr.reduce((acc, str) => ({...acc, [str]: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.increment(item.number)}), {})
}
```

Comment: Do they both work the way you expect?  If so, then pick the one you prefer.  Otherwise, pick the one that actually works.

Comment: @DougStevenson They both seem to work, though I was worried about unforeseen tradeoffs particularly with deeply nested objects. I think A gives me better control and is much easier to prevent accidentally overwriting a map field with an empty map. Thanks!

Comment: Then I suggest editing your question and reword it to ask about your specific concerns.  What you have now reads like it's asking for opinion, which is [off-topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).